# Spring boot, how to access jetty server instance?

Tags: jetty, spring-boot

I'm using "spring-boot-starter-web" with jetty.
After I launch the application, I was able to call rest functions.
Is there any way I can access Jetty instance directly or I can wire Server/Servlet context after the jetty starts?

Answer (score 1):

If you need more control over the embedded Jetty instance, think about using your own [JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/jetty/JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.html). Look at the Spring Boot docs, especially the section [Customizing ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer directly](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-customizing-configurableembeddedservletcontainerfactory-directly). There is an example for using an a TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory but its the same for Jetty (both implementing [ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer.html)).